# Pot size recommendation for this Jade plant

Tags: houseplants, containers

Should I get a small, medium, or large for this Jade plant?

[image]
[image]

The plant looks big, but I am not sure what size of pot to get for this plant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a pot a couple of sizes bigger than the current size of the rootball, so you've got an inch or so of potting soil in the pot surrounding and beneath the rootball, not more than that. Over time as it gets larger and fills the pot, you'll need a bigger one, applying the same rule about size.